# Removing SharePoint Online Top Link Bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, navigation, modern-experience, hub-site

When I am in the new SharePoint view, the top link bar is appearing twice.  When it is in the old classic view, it shows up once.

I checked `/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` and everything appears to look fine there. I am guessing it inherited the old SharePoint information during migration.

Is there a way for me to access that and remove it in SharePoint or using SharePoint Designer?

Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: Or are you using hub sites?

Comment: It may be, how do I check/remove it?  Sorry, it was created awhile back by someone else.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites) for more information on hub sites and if it is a hub site then you can [Unregister a site as a hub site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-hub-site). Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have register this site as a **Hub site**.

You can find more information about hub sites at: [Planning your SharePoint hub sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites)

If it is a hub site then you can unregister it by following below documentation:

[Unregister a site as a hub site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-hub-site)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, it looks like it is a hub site.  Is there a way for me to keep it as a hubsite, but access the data and edit the "top link bar". The hubsite is migrated from SP2013 the site templates are very old.

Comment: Are you able to see the "Edit" option after last link in hub navigation? Something like given [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca) under "Add a link to the hub site navigation bar" section.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Ganesh Sanap said, you could unregister that site as hub site.

Here is the way to using PnP PowerShell command as a supplement.

Open [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) and type following [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Credentials (Get-Credential)
Unregister-PnPHubSite -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myhubsite
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/unregister-pnphubsite?view=sharepoint-ps

More information, you could refer to those documents provided by Ganesh Sanap.