# Removing Hub Navigation on SharePoint Online modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, hub-site

I have created a Hub site and a child site for my hub, since doing this a new navigation bar has appeared on both sites (hub navigation bar). I want to be able to remove this. However I have not found any out of the box way of doing this in SharePoint. Could someone help me with finding the correct solution for this if it is in fact possible? I did run into a page stating it is not possible but it was from 2018 and I am hoping Microsoft has made changes to this by now...

Below is an image showing the navigation bar I want removed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research, you can remove the Hub Navigation by unregistering this site as a hub site. More information, please see **"[Unregister a site as a hub site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-hub-site)"** article.

If you don't want to unregister, then you can choose to hide this navigation.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Go to the hub site as a site admin

2.Settings >> **Hub site settings**

[image]

3.Turn off the "**Shown in navigation**" feature

[image]

4.Save

[image]

[image]

**Here is a similar case for your reference：**

- [Removing SharePoint Online Top Link Bar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288602/removing-sharepoint-online-top-link-bar)

Comment: That seemed to remove all the links in it however when I logged in as a read only user the hub navigation bar still shows up, except now it is completely empty. I was hoping this whole section could be hidden to the end user. This way there is no empty space added to the header. Any idea if this can be done or if that space has to stay there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The hub navigation space will still appear unless you unregister this site as a hub site.